# print out date range from January 1 1910 to December 30 2025

Tags: java, date, for-loop, hashmap, calendar

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Iterator;
public class Details
{
    public static void main(String [] args)
    {
        HashMap<Integer, String> hmap = new HashMap<Integer, String>();
        //Adding elements to HashMap
        hmap.put(1, "January");
        hmap.put(2, "January");
        hmap.put(3, "January");
        hmap.put(4, "January");
        hmap.put(5, "January");
        hmap.put(6, "January");
        hmap.put(7, "January");
        hmap.put(8, "January");
        hmap.put(9, "January");
        hmap.put(10, "January");
        //FOR LOOP
        System.out.println("For Loop:");
        for (Map.Entry me : hmap.entrySet()) {
          System.out.println("Key: "+ me.getKey() + " & Value: " + me.getValue());
        }

        //WHILE LOOP & ITERATOR
        System.out.println("While Loop:");
        Iterator iterator = hmap.entrySet().iterator();
        while (iterator.hasNext()) {
             Map.Entry me2 = (Map.Entry) iterator.next();
          System.out.println("Key: "+ me2.getKey() + " & Value: " + me2.getValue());
        } 
    }
}
```

My output:

```
For Loop:
Key: 1 & Value: January
Key: 2 & Value: January
Key: 3 & Value: January
Key: 4 & Value: January
Key: 5 & Value: January
Key: 6 & Value: January
Key: 7 & Value: January
Key: 8 & Value: January
Key: 9 & Value: January
Key: 10 & Value: January
While Loop:
Key: 1 & Value: January
Key: 2 & Value: January
Key: 3 & Value: January
Key: 4 & Value: January
Key: 5 & Value: January
Key: 6 & Value: January
Key: 7 & Value: January
Key: 8 & Value: January
Key: 9 & Value: January
Key: 10 & Value: January
```

I would like this output:

```
1: January 1, 1910
2: January 2, 1910
3: January 3, 1910
4: January 4, 1910
5: January 5, 1910.....

up to

41758: December 28, 2025
41759: December 29, 2025
41760: December 30, 2025
```

Thanks for the help

Comment: Do you really want to store thousands of date objects in a map and then just output them to the console? Or are you looking for a way to output all days from a specific start date to an end date?

Comment: Yes just print out from January 1, 1910 start date to December 30, 2025. This is an assignment for school which I am stuck on I have tried a lot of other ways not posted here. Thanks @Eritrean

Comment: So this means that we should guide and point you in the right direction and leave as much as possible to yourself so you may learn? And particularly avoid giving you full working code (also known as *spoon-feeding*)?

Comment: I am unsure from where you got the idea that a `HashMap` would help you. I doubt that it can.

Answer (score 4):

You can do it like this.  Check out the [java.time](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/16/docs/api/java.base/java/time/package-summary.html) package for more useful Date/Time classes.

```
import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;
import java.time.temporal.ChronoUnit;


LocalDate start = LocalDate.of(1910,1,1);
LocalDate end = LocalDate.of(2025,12,31);
DateTimeFormatter fmt = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("MMMM d, yyyy");
int key = 1;
while (start.isBefore(end)) {
    System.out.println(key++ + " : " + start.format(fmt));
    start = start.plus(1, ChronoUnit.DAYS);
}
```

Prints something like this.

```
1 : January 1, 1910
2 : January 2, 1910
3 : January 3, 1910
4 : January 4, 1910
5 : January 5, 1910
6 : January 6, 1910
7 : January 7, 1910
8 : January 8, 1910
9 : January 9, 1910
10 : January 10, 1910
11 : January 11, 1910
12 : January 12, 1910
...
...
```

If, on the other hand, you don't want to use any imported classes to do this you can do it as follows:

- Create an array of month names
- Create an array of max days per month (non leap year).
- Create a leap year method (explained later).

```
String[] monthNames = { "January", "February", "March",
        "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September",
        "October", "November", "December" };
int[] monthDays =
        { 31, 28, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31 };
int day = 1;
int month = 0; // months go from 0 to 11
int year = 1910;
int count = 0;
```

A simple while loop driver to print the date range.

```
while (!(year == 2025 && month == 11 && day == 31)) {
    count++;
    System.out.printf("%d : %s %d, %d%n", count,
            monthNames[month], day, year);

     if (day++ >= monthDays[month]) {
         // take care of February in a leap year
         if (month == 1 && day == 29 && isLeap(year)) {
             continue;
         }
         day = 1;        // reset day if past end of month.
         month++;
         if (month == 12) {
             month = 0;  // reset month and increment year
             year++;
         } 
     }
         
}
```

Only non-century years divisible by 4 and century years divisible by 400 are leap years.  Checking non century years first since they occur more frequently.

```
public static boolean isLeap(int year) {
    return year % 100 != 0 && year % 4 == 0 || year % 400 == 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is an approach that will generate the requested data, properly (one hopes) accounting for leap years, etc. I will note that the run does not have the same last number as the example output.

If it is desired to store the data into some data array, replace the `output` method as desired.

```
    private static DateTimeFormatter FMTR = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("MMMM d, yyyy");
    
    public static LocalDate genNextDate(LocalDate inpDate)
    {
        return inpDate.plusDays(1);
    }
    
    
    public static void output(int cntr, LocalDate inpDate)
    {

        System.out.printf("%6d: %s%n", cntr, FMTR.format(inpDate));
    }
    
    
    public static void doIt()
    {
        final LocalDate endDate = LocalDate.of(2025, 12, 31);
        int cntr = 1;
        LocalDate date = LocalDate.of(1910, 1, 1);
        
        while (date.isBefore(endDate)) {
            output(cntr, date);
            date = genNextDate(date);
            cntr++;
        }
    }

   public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        doIt();
    }
```

Example Output

```
     1: January 1, 1910
     2: January 2, 1910
     3: January 3, 1910
     4: January 4, 1910
     5: January 5, 1910
     6: January 6, 1910
     7: January 7, 1910
     8: January 8, 1910
     9: January 9, 1910
     ...
 42364: December 26, 2025
 42365: December 27, 2025
 42366: December 28, 2025
 42367: December 29, 2025
 42368: December 30, 2025
```